# Defining the geometric predicate as a dropdown-input of a model

Tags: qgis-modeler

I built a model and use the tool "Extract by location". I would like to define the geometric predicate as a variable, so the user can choose between different predicates when he/she runs the model. How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The geometric predicate input expects an index, starting from 0 as input as array or comma separated string. E.g. `'1,3'` or `[1,3]` for *`contains`* and *`touches`*. Since using numbers is not quite intuitive, I suggest to use an **Enum-Input**: As already mentioned, the important thing is the order of the items within this input. It has to be the same as it would it be, if you directly choose it from the tool:

[image: ![enter image description here]

So the Enum-Input has the same order (you can also allow multiple input):

[image]

So your model looks like this:

[image]

And the tool:

[image]